# Работа с текстом на java

Tags: java

Программа выдает поток текстовых данных типа:

```
6502-030029

6300-030046

6100-04

6100-02
```

Задача: если последняя часть числа содержит 6 символов разделить их таким образом

```
6502-03-0029

6300-03-0046
```

Comment: что у вас конкретно не получается?

Comment: Конкретно не получается найти точку вхождения для постановки символа "-". Пример: в этом значении 6300-030046 символ должен располагаться так, 6300-03(здесь)0046. Как приравнивать и редактировать по шаблону??

Comment: @ПавелДаушко C lastIndexOf() ищем последний "-", после чего отнимаем от длины полученный индекс... В случае необходимости делаем insert() в нужное место

Comment: @AntonM Спасибо))

Answer (score 2):

Разделяете строку по `-`, проверяете вторую половину на 6 символов и убираете ненужные:

```
static String process(String text) {
    String[] parts = text.split("-");
    if (parts[1].length() == 6) {
        return parts[0] + "-" + parts[1].substring(0, 2) + "-" + parts[1].substring(2);
    }
    return text;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (String text : Arrays.asList("6502-030029", "6300-030046", "6100-04", "6100-02")) {
        System.out.println(process(text));
    }
}
```

---

Еще можно через регулярные выражения (в этом случае описываем шаблон строки).

- `.` - любой символ. Для текущей задачи можно просто цифры искать через `\d` или `[0-9]`, но ради краткости шаблона использую `.`
- `-` - просто тире `-`
- `()` - круглые скобки служат для захвата группы символов, которые после вытаскиваем через `group`

Код:

```
static String processRegExp(String text) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(....-)(..)(....)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    if (m.find()) {
        return m.group(1) + m.group(2) + "-" + m.group(3);
    }
    return text;
}
```

---

Консоль:

```
6502-03-0029
6300-03-0046
6100-04
6100-02
```